# A syslog to Azure Log Analytics forwarder

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, http, rust

I am using this code to forward my syslog logs (converted to json using `syslog-ng`) to Azure Log Analytics on an ARM board (since there is no official client for ARM). It uses the [HTTP Data Collector API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api) to submit the logs.

The idea is to read logs from stdin (each line is a JSON object) in separate thread with a buffer and send them when tokio worker thread is ready or the buffer gets full (body can't be more 30MB).

My questions:

- Is my usage of async Rust correct?
- Is there a way to improve performance?

#### src/main.rs

```rust
use futures::sync::mpsc::channel;
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use hyper::client::HttpConnector;
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use native_tls::{Protocol, TlsConnector};
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::{io, thread};

const AZURE_REQUEST_LIMIT: usize = 30 * 1000 * 1000; // 30 MB
const LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT: usize = AZURE_REQUEST_LIMIT - 2; // should fit in '[' + <30 mb of json> + ']'

fn aggregated_logs() -> impl Stream<Item = String, Error = ()> {
    let (mut tx, rx) = channel(0);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let input = io::stdin();

        let mut lock = input.lock();

        let mut buf = String::new();
        loop {
            let empty = buf.is_empty();

            let c = if empty { '[' } else { ',' };
            buf.push(c);

            let mut read_bytes = lock.read_line(&mut buf).expect("failed to read line");
            if read_bytes == 0 && empty {
                break;
            }

            // remove newline
            read_bytes -= 1;
            buf.pop();

            assert!(
                read_bytes <= LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT,
                "line is too long: {} bytes",
                read_bytes
            );
            let under_limit = buf.len() <= AZURE_REQUEST_LIMIT - 1;

            let mut msg = if under_limit {
                // send the entire buffer
                std::mem::replace(&mut buf, String::new())
            } else {
                // buffer got too big, save next line for next iteration
                let prev_len = buf.len() - read_bytes;
                let mut msg = String::from("[");
                msg.push_str(&buf[prev_len..]);

                buf.truncate(prev_len);
                std::mem::replace(&mut buf, msg)
            };

            msg.push(']');

            while let Err(e) = tx.try_send(msg) {
                debug_assert!(e.is_full());
                msg = e.into_inner();
                if under_limit {
                    buf = msg;
                    buf.pop(); // remove ']'
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    rx
}

const RESOURCE: &'static str = "/api/logs";
const CONTENT_TYPE: &'static str = "application/json";
const X_MS_DATE: &'static str = "x-ms-date";

type HmacSha256 = hmac::Hmac<sha2::Sha256>;
use hmac::Mac;

fn signature(rfc1123date: &str, len: usize, customer_id: &str, mut hmac: HmacSha256) -> String {
    let string_to_hash = format!(
        "POST\n{}\n{}\n{}:{}\n{}",
        len, CONTENT_TYPE, X_MS_DATE, rfc1123date, RESOURCE
    );
    hmac.input(string_to_hash.as_bytes());
    let result = hmac.result();
    let base64 = base64::encode(&result.code());
    format!("SharedKey {}:{}", customer_id, base64)
}

fn main() {
    let customer_id = std::env::var("CUSTOMER_ID").expect("Missing CUSTOMER_ID");
    let shared_key = std::env::var("SHARED_KEY").expect("Missing SHARED_KEY");
    let log_type = std::env::var("LOG_TYPE").expect("Missing LOG_TYPE");
    let time_generated = std::env::var("TIME_GENERATED_FIELD");

    let decoded_key = base64::decode(&shared_key).unwrap();
    let hmac = HmacSha256::new_varkey(&decoded_key).unwrap();

    let mut http = HttpConnector::new(num_cpus::get());
    http.enforce_http(false);

    let connector = TlsConnector::builder()
        .min_protocol_version(Some(Protocol::Tlsv12))
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let mut https: HttpsConnector<_> = (http, connector).into();
    https.https_only(true);
    let client = hyper::Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(https);
    let uri = format!(
        "https://{}.ods.opinsights.azure.com{}?api-version=2016-04-01",
        customer_id, RESOURCE
    );

    tokio::run(
        aggregated_logs()
            .then(move |data| {
                let data = data.unwrap();
                let rfc1123date = chrono::Utc::now()
                    .format("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
                    .to_string();

                let len = data.len();
                let signature = signature(&rfc1123date, len, &customer_id, hmac.clone());

                let body: hyper::Body = data.into();

                let mut builder = hyper::Request::post(&uri);
                builder
                    .header("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE)
                    .header("Content-Length", len)
                    .header("Authorization", signature)
                    .header("Log-Type", log_type.as_str())
                    .header(X_MS_DATE, rfc1123date);

                if let Ok(time_generated) = &time_generated {
                    builder.header("time-generated-field", time_generated.as_str());
                }
                let request = builder.body(body).unwrap();
                client.request(request).and_then(
                    |response| -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = hyper::Error> + Send> {
                        let status = response.status();
                        if status.is_success() {
                            Box::new(futures::finished(()))
                        } else {
                            Box::new(response.into_body().concat2().and_then(move |chunk| {
                                let message = String::from_utf8(chunk.to_vec()).unwrap();
                                eprintln!("{} {}", status, message);
                                Ok(())
                            }))
                        }
                    },
                )
            })
            .for_each(|_| Ok(()))
            .then(|e| {
                e.unwrap();
                Ok(())
            }),
    )
}
```

#### Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "log_analytics"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
tokio = "0.1.13"
hyper = "0.12.19"
futures = "0.1.25"
hmac = "0.7.0"
sha2 = "0.8.0"
hyper-tls = "0.3.1"
chrono = "0.4.6"
base64 = "0.10.0"
native-tls = "0.2.2"
num_cpus = "1.9.0"
```

Comment: `let under_limit = buf.len() <= AZURE_REQUEST_LIMIT - 1;` is either an error or over complication for `let under_limit = buf.len() < AZURE_REQUEST_LIMIT;`

Comment: Your code sample helped me with TimeGenerated issue. Thanks!